# Changing var name from array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, variables

I have been struggling with changing the column name from the array of objects. One of the column name contain spaces.

```
var array = [{"First Name":"John", "Last Name":"Doe", "age":46}, {"First Name":"Tim", "Last Name":"Jones", "age":26}, {"First Name":"Marcus", "Last Name":"Brown", "age":31}, {"First Name":"Paul", "Last Name":"Daniels", "age":28}];
```

I want to change the object column name to firstName or first_name so the array could be the following:

```
var array = [{"first_name":"John", "Last Name":"Doe", "age":46}, {"first_name":"Tim", "Last Name":"Jones", age:26}, {"first_name":"Marcus", "Last Name":"Brown", "age":31}, {"first_name":"Paul", "Last Name":"Daniels", "age":28}];
```

I tried mapping like this, but it didn't work since i can do that inside a map function:

```
...
 .map(({ [First Name], age}) => ({ [First Name], age}))
...
```

I want to change the column name before mapping it so I would do something like this:

```
...
 .map(({ first_name, age}) => ({ first_name, age}))
...
```

Comment: Well `First Name:"John"` is a syntax error so is it actually `"First Name":"John"`

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mapKeys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, I modified your JSON to be valid, now you can loop over it and create a new object with the desired results:

```js
let array = [{"First Name": "John", "Last Name":"Doe", age:46}, {"First Name":"Tim", "Last Name":"Jones", age:26}, {"First Name":"Marcus", "Last Name":"Brown", age:31}, {"First Name":"Paul", "Last Name":"Daniels", age:28}];

let modifiedArray = array.map(item => {
   return {
     first_name: item["First Name"],
     "Last Name": item["Last Name"],
     age: item.age
   }
 });

console.log(modifiedArray);
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: This definitely helped me. Thank You!